# Обрезаются названия товаров в магазине на CMS Opencart

Tags: php, html, cms, opencart, ecommerce

Из за чего может криво отбражаться название товара в категориях?

Уже искал где обрезается название товара, но ничего не нашел.
CMS Opencart 2.3
Тема Melani от Plazathemes.

Может у кого то было такое.
Пример:
C03 Браслет с бусинами �...

[image: Пример отображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась Изменениям строки в модификаторе theme.ocmod.xml
$result['name'] = strlen($result['name']) > 40 ?substr($result['name'],0,40)."..." : $result['name'];

- изменения строки в catalog/controller/extension/module/oclayerednavigation.php
  $result['name'] = strlen($result['name']) > 40 ? mb_substr($result['name'],0,40)."..." : $result['name'];

Answer (score 1):

Тут дело скорее всего в вашей теме к OpenCart. Посмотрите контроллер catalog/controller/product/category.php и файл представления catalog/view/theme/название вашей темы/template/product/category.tpl.

Как вариант еще можно посмотреть настройки самой темы.

Comment: Смотрел но в теме нет данного файла(
Есть пару модулей на которые я грешу 
но там тоже ничего не нашел(

Могу дать backup сайта